# display serial number over each letter of String. PHP

Tags: php, string, indexing

I have a string with single letter codes like
MGCLGNSKTEDQRNEEKAQREAMGCLGNSKTEDQRNEEKAQREAMGCLGNSKTEDQRNEEKAQREA
I would like to print a serial number over each letter in the string.

like

```
123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930  
MGCLGNSKTED Q R N E E K A Q R E A M G C L G N S K T
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean a consecutive number? 1, 2, 3...? Is the output plain text or HTML?

Answer (score 2):

A nice excuse to learn about some fancy PHP functions:

```
<?php

$single_letter_codes = 'MGCLGNSKTEDQRNEEKAQREAMGCLGNSKTEDQRNEEKAQREAMGCLGNSKTEDQRNEEKAQREA';

foreach(range(1, strlen($single_letter_codes)) as $number){
    echo $number;
}
echo PHP_EOL;

foreach(str_split($single_letter_codes) as $index => $letter){
    // Changed ' ' to '·' to make it visible
    echo str_pad($letter, strlen($index+1), '·', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Assumptions:

- Single byte strings
- Right align, as in:

  ```
  10
   A
  ```

And we get:

```
123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566
MGCLGNSKT·E·D·Q·R·N·E·E·K·A·Q·R·E·A·M·G·C·L·G·N·S·K·T·E·D·Q·R·N·E·E·K·A·Q·R·E·A·M·G·C·L·G·N·S·K·T·E·D·Q·R·N·E·E·K·A·Q·R·E·A
```

**Update:** In order to display this as HTML, you need to enforce a fixed width font. The simplest way is to enclose everything into a `<pre></pre>` tag set.

I'll leave as an exercise for the reader how to use spaces instead of dots.

Comment: thanks , worked, but if letter like O and P are present, the display of string is shifted to right-hand side.

Comment: That's not true. You are problaby not generating plain text. I asked one hour ago but never got an answer :)

Comment: im sorry for late reply. im generating output for html. and der shud not be dots. spaces needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, then this is what you need (caution, there might be small mistakes, test):

```
function printSerial($string){
   $map = array(
      'M' => 1,
      'G' => 2,
      'C' => 3,
      // ... please continue
   );
   $output = '';
   for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){
      $output .= $map[$string[$i]];
   }
   echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help...

```
<?php

$str = 'MGCLGNSKTEDQRNEEKAQREAMGCLGNSKTEDQRNEEKAQREAMGCLGNSKTEDQRNEEKAQREA';
$len = strlen($str);
$nums = '';
$lets = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++) {
    $nums .= $i;
    $lets .= sprintf('% ' . strlen($i) . 's', $str[$i - 1]);
}
echo $nums . "\n" . $lets;
```

You will get

```
123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566
MGCLGNSKT E D Q R N E E K A Q R E A M G C L G N S K T E D Q R N E E K A Q R E A M G C L G N S K T E D Q R N E E K A Q R E A
```